Доступность клиента после смены IP посредством Ansible
Через Ansible я меняю сетевые настройки, копируя файл interfaces. Затем перезапускаю сервис networking. Как я вижу на клиенте, все задачи выполнены, но сервер с которого я запускаю - висит на задаче Restart networking, очевидно пытаясь соединиться со старым ip адресом. Хотя я и указал параметр async.
Вот сами задачи:
- name: "Change network settings to {{ client }}"
  template:
    src: interfaces.j2
    dest: /etc/network/interfaces
    mode: '0644'

- name: Restart networking
  command: systemctl restart networking
  async: 1
  poll: 0

Подскажите, как можно в задаче указать завершение выполнения, а не ожидание конца этой задачи.

попробуйте systemctl restart networking &
